# Password hashing for 2 way?

Tags: java, spring

I know it is weird, but jut to be sure, I am wondering if it is possible to decode a encoded password using Spring Security?

As it is mostly used, we match the password with the encyrpted password retrieved from the database. There are some issues on SO, but all of them just using match passwords. Any other workaround for this using `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder` ?

Comment: If you can "decode" a user's password then you didn't store that password properly in the first place.  User passwords should be obscured behind an irreversible 1-way hashing algorithm so they can never be returned to their original state.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good explanations. OK.

Answer (score 3):

Password encoding in Spring Security is one way done using hashing algorithms, you can't decode it back.

Spring encoded the password and saves it in the database, while checking the entered password it encoded the entered password and compared it with the saved encoded password.